# delay in schedule as KPI?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, kpi

In Microsoft Project 2013, what is the best way to show delay in schedule as KPI?
In EPM, I want to highlight the projects with more than 20% of schedule delay.

Comment: What do you mean by "show"?  Are you asking how to calculate the delay, which column shows the delay, or simply how to exhibit it in project to communicate the delay?

Comment: If you have saved a baseline, the Variance table will show start and finish date variance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to ensure that every project housed on the EPM Server is a) baselined and b) has progress added and any late tasks have been reforcasted. 
You could run a calculation I belive that would look at your project summary line and calculate what percentage of the overall duration the projects finish variance worked out as, and then using an icon to show any results on your server that were 20% or more.

It's a bit fiddly though and provbably requires cusome fields and calculations.

An easier approach might be to set a tolerance (in days) for finish variance for all projects and then just highlight any that breach the tolerance.